# BindingInformation in Microsoft.Web.Administration

Tags: asp.net, iis, web, administration

I try to create new site:

```
    ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager();
    Site addedSite = iisManager.Sites.Add(siteName, siteFolder, 80);
    addedSite.ServerAutoStart = true;

    iisManager.CommitChanges();
```

And it add site but I need to have in IIS binding information "test.com"

How can I add that ?
Aslo somehow added site is stopped...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following constructor to set binding information. Found from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359364%28VS.90%29.aspx)

```
ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager();
Site addedSite = iisManager.Sites.Add(siteName,"http","*:80:www.example.com", siteFolder);
```

Where * is the server ip address that you would like to bind to the hostname www.example.com, or leave as * to catch all requests from any server ip.